# c# Bot Builder SDK - Approach for Disambiguation

Tags: botframework

I'm building a LuisDialog and have LUIS integration working well.

In the cases where LUIS doesnt fill in all the gaps I need, what is the best approach for disambiguation?

Right now, I use PromptDialog callbacks - So inside a Dialog method (decorated with the LuisIntent attribute), when I need to get more details/disambiguate i'd have:

```
PromptDialog.Choice<string>(context, EnsureTimeOfDayChosen, new[] { "Morning (AM)", "Afternoon (PM)", "Any" }, "What time of day would you like us to book the appointment? (AM/PM/Any)", "Please choose AM or PM.  Alternatively, if you don't mind which, just say Any.");
```

And the delegate's body (EnsureTimeOfDayChosen):

```
string AmPmOrAny = await result;
context.PerUserInConversationData.SetValue<string>("TimeOfDay", AmPmOrAny);
BookAppointment(context);
```

The problem with this approach is the last line of the delegate - it doesn't feel right.  I can't easily call back into the place I was in the initially called, LuisIntent decorated method and resume.

Instead, I have to deal with the LUIS info up front, and call the BookAppointment method after gathering more info, and storing it in PerUserInConversationData.

Am I doing it wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Kind Regards,
Matt.

Answer (score 1):

Given current implementation of the Dialog model, I cannot think of a better way of implementing your logic. Currently anytime that you are waiting on an async response from the user, your code will be resumed on the callback you provided upon response. You can think of it as [Begin/End model for async programing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx)